# JAVA: generics method invocation

Tags: java, generics

What I have:

1. A normal class with generic type:

Source:

```
class Normal <T> {
    private int field1;
    private String field2;
    SomeCollection<T> data; // i.e. List or Set
}
```

2. A method with argument:

Source:

```
public void work((new Normal<SomeType>()).class) {xxx}
```

My question is:

I want a `work()` method to embed `Normal` class, but just expose `SomeType.class` as argument, so that caller does not need to know `Normal` class. How can I do this? For example:

```
public void work(SomeType.class) {new Normal<someTypeClass>();}
```

Comment: What does that even mean

Comment: The syntax could not be less correct. Please improve your question. ``do`` is a keyword, ``getclass()`` does not exist, you can't pass values in a method declaration, what is ``do`` even supposed to ``do``?

Comment: For now I suspect that you may be looking for generic method, but I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: What about `public void do(Class class) { // your stuff }`?

Comment: hi all, i've updated my question, and please also refer to the comment i leave in @Christophe Schutz's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is :

```
public void do(T param) {xxx}
```

If not, I really didn't get your question.

That being said, the caller still has to instantiate the Normal class, since it's not a static method and since T type is depending on the Normal instantiation.

Comment: yes, the caller only knows his own T class, but does not know `Normal` class. while `do(T)` method would generate Normal<T> object.